# ftp_connect Couldn't connect to $ftp_server

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to make a scrip that will log in to an FTP folder and download everything from that folder to the folder where the PHP Script lives on another server. I cannot get the FTP_CONNECT function to connect or give me relevant error to identify the issue.

```
<?php
//establish connection variables 
$ftp_server = ""; 
$ftp_port="";
$ftp_serusername="";
$ftp_serpass="";

//setup basic configuration
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,'21') 
or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_serusername, $ftp_serpass);

//check connection 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
echo "FTP Connection Failed to Login"; 
}

ftp_sync (".");    // Use "." if you are in the current directory 

ftp_close($conn_id);  

// ftp_sync - Copy directory and file structure 
function ftp_sync ($dir) { 

global $conn_id; 

if ($dir != ".") { 
    if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir) == false) { 
        echo ("Change Dir Failed: $dir<BR>\r\n"); 
        return; 
    } 
    if (!(is_dir($dir))) 
        mkdir($dir); 
    chdir ($dir); 
} 

$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); 
foreach ($contents as $file) { 

    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
        continue; 

    if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $file)) { 
        ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
        ftp_sync ($file); 
    } 
    else 
        ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY); 
} 

ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
chdir (".."); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled. `ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: This question **should be deleted now**. You gave publicly the IP, the login and the password of your FTP. Editing won't change anything, since the edit history can be seen.

Comment: ^ That's a big issue so you better follow the recommendations above. Delete the post and ask it again (_without_ any real credentials).

Comment: Even if you delete the post (and you should), you should also change the password.  That appears to be a godaddy IP, some godaddy services will let you change your IP; you should also consider that.

Comment: Oh geez, he posted the question and went to get coffee. It's probably already too late - someone has likely logged in and started mucking about.

Comment: You think I would give ROOT to an FTP Cred posted publicly? This a dummy account, in a dummy folder, I couldn't care less what happens in a sandbox. Really people.

Comment: Functions execute with no errrors on the server BTW - if I want any kind of error output it will have to be written into the script, and I don't know PHP ftp_connect well enough to have an response expectations to create error handling.

Comment: Well, as your question does not not show any real attempt to debug the problem, you cannot be surprised that people have low expectations. --- Next time you post dummy credentials, make sure it's clear that those are dummy credentials. And do not post random IP address, even more so if that IP address really exists. There are reserved IP addresses and host names for example purposes (like `example.com`).

Comment: Anyway, do you have PHP errors/warnings enabled? Or did you at least tried to call `error_get_last`? Can you connect to that FTP server using *any* FTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something to do with using this script in a PHP 5.6 environment.
Upgraded to PHP 7.2 and everything works.
Again this never generated any server errors, there was nothing to clue me in to what was going wrong.

Comment: errors are logged in a file named error_log, you can find its path in the php.ini file. it's also possible to enable them manually in a file with `init_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, that will output them on the screen.